# Binding image in AutoCompleteExtender like facebook?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have an ajax AutoCompleteExtender. I am able to bind the text only with my AutoCompleteExtender not image. So How can i bind the image and text in an ajax AutoCompleteExtender? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

*Add below mentioned files in your header section*

```
   <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {




        $("#searchtext").autocomplete
       ({
           source:
          function (request, response) {
              $.ajax
              ({
                  url: "../BeanService.asmx/GetCompletionList",
                  data: "{prefixText:'" + request.term + "'}",   // term is the property that contains the entered text
                  dataType: "json",
                  type: "POST",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  success: function (data) {



                      response(data["d"]);  // property d contains list of names sent from service
                      //$("#dynamiccontainer").append(data["d"]);


                  },
                  error: function (xhr, callStatus, errorThrown) {
                      // alert(callStatus);
                  }
              });
          },
           // Attempt to remove click/select functionality - may be a better way to do this        
           select: function (event, ui) {


               var mylink = ui.item.value;

               var doc = document.createElement("html");
               doc.innerHTML = mylink;
               var links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
               var urls = [];

               for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                   urls.push(links[i].getAttribute("href"));
               }




               window.location.href = urls[0];


               return false;
           }


       });
    });

</script>
```

*Below is the Textbox on which autocomplete will be applied*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchtext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

*This is your bean class which will be filled by webservice and returned to jquery method through ajax call*

```
public class SearchBean
{

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string reUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string stype
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string photoAdd
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

*This is your webservice which will be called by your jquery automplete ajax method*

```
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText)
{
    BDBEntities db = new BDBEntities();
    List<SearchBean> lstfinaldata = new List<SearchBean>();
    List<MaCatMaster> lstcatlist = db.MaCatMasters.Where(z => z.CatName.Contains(prefixText) && z.Status == true).ToList();



    foreach (MaCatMaster obj in lstcatlist)
    {
        SearchBean objbean = new SearchBean();
        objbean.Id = obj.Id;
        objbean.Title = obj.CatName;
        objbean.stype = "Category";
        objbean.reUrl = www.demo.com + "/Pages/Coupons/" + obj.Id;
        lstfinaldata.Add(objbean);
    }




    string[] st = new string[lstfinaldata.Count];
    int i = 0;


    foreach (SearchBean obj in lstfinaldata)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html><body>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<a href='{0}' name='urllink'>", obj.reUrl);
        sb.Append("<table width='420px'>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td width='60px'><img src='{0}' style='border:1px solid #eeeeee' width='60px' height='40px'></td><td align='left' width='300px'>{1}</td><td align='left' width='60px' style='font-size:14px;'>{2}</td></tr>", obj.photoAdd, obj.Title, obj.stype);
        sb.Append("</table>");
        sb.Append("</a>");
        sb.Append("</body></html>");
        st[i] = sb.ToString();
        i++;
    }

    return st;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your search method you can use `AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem()` method to create pairs of the *text to display* and the *image path*:

```
public static List<string> Search(string prefixText, int count)
{
  var items = new List<string>();

  // ...

  items.Add(AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(
          text,
          imagePath));

  // ...

  return items;
}
```

Then create the `img` tags on the client side with a javascript:

```
function Items_Populated(sender, e) {

  var items = sender.get_completionList().childNodes;

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    var div = document.createElement(“div”);
    div.innerHTML = ”<img src=' + items[i]._value + ’ /><br />”;

    items[i].appendChild(div);
}
```

Here are some examples:

- [AJAX AutoComplete with prefix image](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43368/AJAX-AutoComplete-with-prefix-image)
- [Auto Complete with images](http://ashuthinks.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/auto-complete-with-images/)